# How do I pass info from one activity's EditText to another for the url to be loaded in that new activity's WebView?

Tags: java, android, webview

all! I have been searching through StackOverflow for a few hours now and cannot find a solution to my problem.

I am developing an android app that needs to take input from the user in one activity through an EditText (this happens to be an int value). I then need that EditText's int value to be passed to a second activity, and parsed into a url to be loaded into a webview in that second activity. However, I cannot get this to work. In fact, I cannot get my WebView to work at all, even trying to load websites like Google. Below is my code.

```
public void takeInput(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, WebViewActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        Integer vendorID = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_VENDORID, vendorID);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Above is the method that is called when an onscreen button is pressed OnClick.

The code from the next activity is below.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);
    String testURL2 = "www.google.com";
    WebView streetwiseSite = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    streetwiseSite.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    String vendorID = extras.getString(MainActivity.EXTRA_VENDORID);
    Integer vendorID = Integer.parseInt(extras.getString(MainActivity.EXTRA_VENDORID));
    String targetURL = "www.something.org/purchase/";
```

Here is the XML code for my first activity.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/logo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="MobilePay"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:hint="Vendor ID #"
        android:inputType="number" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
        android:onClick="takeInput"
        android:text="Pay" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:text="Enter Vendor ID and"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Payment Amount to Pay"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my XML code for the WebView activity, the second activity.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.august.streetwise.WebViewActivity">


    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Ideally this should take the user's input, parse  it into the URL, and load that website. However, here are the errors I get from logcat.

> 04-21 23:36:14.837  17904-17904/com.myname.app W/BindingManager﹕ Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 17904

Any ideas? I've been pulling my hair out over this.

Comment: your passing int and trying to get string in activityB

Comment: extras.getIntExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_VENDORID) try this in ActivityB

Comment: Error in this



String vendorID = extras.getString(MainActivity.EXTRA_VENDORID);
    Integer vendorID = Integer.parseInt(extras.getString(MainActivity.EXTRA_VENDORID));

Comment: @rajahsekar and Mohammed Imran N, thanks for the response. I just implemented this. However, I still get the error "W/BindingManager﹕ Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 28797". Any ideas on how to tackle this? I can't even load google in my webview. Might it be an issue with my XML or something else? I'm at a loss, personally.

Comment: provide your xml and code

Comment: @rajahsekar I just updated my original post with my XML code!

Comment: check this Post : https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=469099

Comment: @rajahsekar I just checked it. What can I do with that? I don't think I understand that post. It seems to be commits to the actual Chromium OS project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WebView.loadUrl()` does not add any protocol formatting to the beginning of the string.  Therefore, `www.something.org` does not automatically become `http://www.something.org`.

Without the protocol information at the beginning of the string, `WebView.loadUrl()` throws the decidedly unhelpful error `W/BindingManager﹕ Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid` because `www.something.org` isn't a complete URL.

You would think this behavior would be documented somewhere.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

change the following line

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, WebViewActivity.class);
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
Integer vendorID = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
 Bundle bn=new Bundle();
bn.putInt(EXTRA_VENDORID, vendorID);
intent.putExtras(bn);

startActivity(intent);
```

in second activity

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);
String testURL2 = "www.google.com";
WebView streetwiseSite =(WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
streetwiseSite.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
int vendorID = extras.getInt(MainActivity.EXTRA_VENDORID);
String targetURL = "www.something.org/purchase/";
```

and for passing this vendorid to a url you should do something like this

```
 String targetURL = "www.something.org/purchase&KEYWORD="+vendorID;
```

nb:KEYWORD should be the exact word which is used in the api side of the url which you are using

try this to load url in webview

```
web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.loadUrl(targetURL);
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This is an awesome response.  However, my app is still not working after implementing all this. I still get the same error: 'W/BindingManager﹕ Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 28797'

Comment: copy the string inside the targetUrl and open it in ur browser is it working?pass it along with the parameter I mean vendorid in your case

Comment: Yes, it works in my browser on both my testing device (Nexus 7) and my laptop. I get the same error no matter what URL I try to go to in my WebView, including "www.google.com". I am at a loss right now.

Comment: @AugustMeyer check my edit in my answer and try the same

Comment: I did all this, and I still get the same `W/BindingManager﹕ Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 17904` error. I even tried instantiating a webview in the main activity, rather than my second webview activity, just to try to load any website in a webview. Webviews don't seemingly work no matter where I put them.